# String to Stack and Queue

Tags: java, string, stack, queue

I'm reading a string but before it's pushed in the stack and enqueued it in queue I need to eliminate all spaces and punctuation while maintaining the order.

I am new to Java and have tried below code which *throws exception*:

```
     for (int i = 0;i < input.length(); i++){
            String character = Character.toString(input.charAt(i));
            if (charChecker(character)){
                stack.push(character);
                queue.enqueue(character);
            }
        }

    private static boolean charChecker (String character) {
        if (character.equals(" ") || character.equals(".") ||
            character.equals("?") || character.equals("!") ||
            character.equals(",") || character.equals(";") ||
            character.equals(":") || character.equals("-"))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    int diff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        String char1 = stack.pop();
        String char2 = queue.dequeue();
        if (!(char1.equalsIgnoreCase(char2))) {
            diff++;
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Enter file name: input1.txt
evil live
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
  at Stack.pop(Stack.java:22)
  at Palindrome.main(Palindrome.java:57)
```

Comment: The error you posted comes from a line where you call `Stack.pop` but in the code you posted you never call `pop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are popping the wrong amount of times.

You do not put `input.legnth()` number of characters on the stack, but are calling pop() that many times. This is because you do not place the white-space and punctuation characters onto the stack.

Try using:

```
while(!stack.empty()) {
        String char1 = stack.pop();
        String char2 = queue.dequeue();
        if (!(char1.equalsIgnoreCase(char2))) {
            diff++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you can't just do:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("[.?!,;:-]", "");
```

For all punctuation and spaces you can use `\W`:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

Comment: probably because he is learning java and does not know about such functions.

Comment: what about spaces, how can I eliminate those using this?

Comment: @user1354275 I've added an answer for **all** punctuation and spaces. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot easier and effective.

Comment: @JProg No problem, glad I could help. The Java API is pretty extensive, there's often a function that will provide what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

***Please post complete code snippet as the code snippet doesn't include lines which are throwing error.***

It says the stack on which you are attempting `pop()` operation is empty. Are you sure that `pop` is being invoked post pushing something on Stack.

I am quite sure that the you are attempting `pop` operation before putting anything on to the stack.